# Nginx server blocks are not working

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, digital-ocean, ubuntu-16.04

I have created 2 server blocks successfully using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) on a digital ocean droplet (virtual private server).

I tried creating two more using the same method, but I am just getting a white screen when I visit the domain listed in server_name (i.e. example.com).

I have restarted nginx, and rebooted my server.

**How should I test if my configuration is working  ?**

Here is my "example.com" config from /etc/nginx/sites-available. It is sym-linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Here is my /var/www/example.com/html/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to example.com</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:#444444;">
        <h1>Success. The example.com server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Using a DNS lookup tool, it shows that visiting my domain returns my server's IP address. But when I `wget example.com`, the index.html file that downloads is from the domain registrar, not my `/var/www/example.com/html/index.html` Is this just DNS propagation being slow?**

Comment: Can you add some clarity regarding the sentence "DNS says the IP address is hitting my server in ..." What is your expectation? and what are you observing?

Comment: Updated: Using a DNS lookup tool, it shows that visiting my domain returns my server's IP address.

Comment: If anyone visits your server they already have your IP address. That is how DNS works. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have 4 domains pointed at my server and configured with nginx server blocks (virtual hosts). Two of my domains, work perfectly. The newest 2 just show a white page, and not the index.html file I'd like to show. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think I see now. DNS propegation may be different on the DNS Testing site vs. the DNS servers you are using. However, there are other ways to test.

### Creating a Hosts file entry:

File locations are as follows:

```
linux: /etc/hosts
windows: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
```

You open the file up and add an entry for your new hostname and ip. Example using `1.2.3.4` as the target IP and `example.com` as the hostname:

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1         localhost.localdomain   localhost
1.2.3.4     example.com
```

Now when you do a `wget` or `curl` it will point to the server at 1.2.3.4 instead of doing a DNS lookup.

### Manually specifying the HOST: header using telnet:

You can also do the GET request manually with telnet and specify the different hostname you are testing. Here is an example connecting to a google server and specifying a different host name:

```
[ttucker@localhost tmp]$ telnet 216.58.217.206 80
Trying 216.58.217.206...
Connected to 216.58.217.206. 
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: example.com

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1561
Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 19:57:18 GMT
....
```

Note: you need to hit `<enter>` twice after the "HOST" header, it is looking for `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: I thought a hosts file was so that I could test a webserver configuration without actually owning the domain? I have discovered something strange. When I try to view website on my phone, it works! On my desktop, I cleared my browser cache, and it still didn't work. Then I enabled a VPN, and my website worked on my desktop! I'm so confused. Does my modem have a cache, or my ISP?

Comment: Thanks @varlogtim for your thoughful anser. I've uncovered a bit more about my problem, and made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729135/website-works-on-phone-but-not-desktop-unless-through-vpn

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't working because the DNS nameservers set on my router were not updated, but the nameservers for my phone used IPv6, and were updated, and my VPN was updated, leading to my confustion.